# Foreach loop to get an IEnumerable<T>

Tags: c#, generics, ienumerable

When using a `foreach` loop to loop through a collection of values types, is it necessary to get an `IEnumerable<T>` interface instead of a non-generic `IEnumerable` interface, to prevent the unwanted intermediate luggage instructions unbox to appear in your compiled code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> is it necessary

It certainly is not *necessary* (necessary in this context means required).

Is it a good idea: yes. Saving unboxing in most cases will be a micro-optimisation (except in the inner loops of CPU limited data processing). But if you know you have a collection of some type of value type then keeping that information does not waste time on a box-unbox cycle and makes the code easier to work with.

The last point, given IDE's intellisense like capabilities, is by far the most valuable.

Answer (score 2):

There is no reason to implement the non-generic `IEnumerable` nowadays, yourself. There are cases where you'll be forced to use it, for example in collections that rely on the old `IEnumerable` implementation, where you have no control.

It is mainly there for backwards-compatibility to the date before generics came to the framework (.NET 1.0). When you want to implement an iterator, use `IEnumerable<T>`, always.

Comment: There are quite a few collections (especially in the UI libraries) that have collections not implementing `IEnumerable<T>`. While `Cast` and `OfType` can be applied, that has the same overhead as the `foreach` itself doing the unboxing.

Comment: @Richard - I was mainly referring to implementing `IEnumerable<T>` yourself, no the use of custom UI collections that don't support it. I think it's pretty trivial that when you don't have a choice, you'll need to use it.

Comment: Accepted, but – as is all too often the case – as I wrote my answer I realised that it is a very poor question. Not only the use of the word "necessary" (meaning required), but then asking about a micro-optimisation. I agree there is almost no reason not to have all custom collections be generic (I can think of custom name-value property sets needing to allow any type of value) but then why is one creating ones own collections?

Comment: @Richard I agree, the OP should clarify what exactly he's trying to do. We can only imagine what he meant and try to respond to that.